# Chrome inspect element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to create something similar to the inspect dom feature in Chrome's devtools.

Which when on hover a - preset list of doms - a `div.shadow` is created on top of the dom with the same width/height covering it, and when mouse leaves, the shadow is hidden or in case a new selected dom is hovered it changes place and dimensions.

```
dom.mouseover(function(e) {
  shadow.css({
    display: "block",
    width: dom.width+"px",
    height: dom.height+"px",
    top: dom.top+"px",
    left: dom.left+"px"
  });
});

shadow.mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).css('display', 'none');
});;
```

But the problem arises when having parent/children in the selected dom lists like "body" where it put the shadow on the body but then ignore any mouseover/mouseenter from children.

Comment: I think you will have to bind the events to `mousemove` and find the element which is a the spicific `x` and `y` position using `elementFromPoint`.

Comment: If i understand your issue, you should use mouseenter instead of mouseover and use inside handler: `e.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tested and fully working

```
var shadow = $('<div></div>').css({background: 'rgba(100,0,0,0.5)', position: 'absolute'}).appendTo('body');
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    shadow.hide();

    var x = e.clientX, y = e.clientY,
        dom = $(document.elementFromPoint(x, y));

    if(dom.length < 1)
        return;

    shadow.css({
        display: "block",
        width: dom[0].offsetWidth +"px",
        height: dom[0].offsetHeight +"px",
        top: dom.position().top +"px",
        left: dom.position().left +"px"
   });

   shadow.show();
});
```

Comment: but still body take full priority and i should move my mouse from the body to be able to highlight something again

Comment: Well, I only tested it in Chrome and Opera, but I don't think there is much browser specificity so it should work the same elsewhere too.

Comment: a side not: i think offset() is better than position() to avoid quirky shadows

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using an outline rather than covering the currently selected element?  When the element is covered you can't use `mousemove` to give you the hovered target element (since the top-most element will always be the shadow).  This requires the shadow to be hidden and shown each time `mousemove` fires which hurts perf.

See this example which just uses an outline and the target element from `mousemove`: http://jsfiddle.net/U4fBu/3/

```
var _prevElm, _prevOutline;

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    if (_prevElm != e.target) {
        // Restore old outline styles
        if (_prevElm) _prevElm.style.outline = _prevOutline;
        // Outline the newly hovered element
        _prevElm = e.target;
        _prevOutline = _prevElm.style.outline;
        e.target.style.outline = "3px solid #0f0";

    }
});

document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // Don't let the click affect the actual page
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var elm = e.target;
    output.innerHTML = "Element clicked: "
        + elm.tagName
        + (elm.id ? "#" + elm.id : "");
});
```

Comment: Yes you can, just use css property `pointer-events: none` and you're free to click through and hover elements behind. ;)

Comment: yeah it seems like most sites goes that road and i went this purely ascetics XD since devtools/firebug use the same principle

Answer (score 0):

What you need is: `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)`

- You have to hide the shadow (display: none),
- get the coordinates of your mouse from the event,
- use `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)`to get the element you're over
- set the visibility of your shadow back to normal.

See http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/tests/elementfrompoint.html how it works.

This, you can't do with mouseover though,... you have to use `mousemove`